# Setting a maximum RAM usage of an interactive session in Pydev

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, pydev

Is there a way to set a maximum allowed RAM usage in an interactive PyDev session? My computer tends to hang if I accidently type a command that causes the RAM usage to swell.

Answer (score 3):

On Unix, you can limit the amount of resources (such as memory) available to the process using [resource.setrlimit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html#resource.setrlimit). For example, to limit the maximum area of address space to 10**6 bytes:

```
import sys
import resource

resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, (10 ** 6, 10 ** 6))
memory_hog = {}
try:
    for x in range(10000):
        memory_hog[str(x)] = 'The sky is so blue'
except MemoryError as err:
    sys.exit('memory exceeded')
    # memory exceeded
```

With the call to `resource.setrlimit`,  `MemoryError` is raised because `memory_hog` takes too much space. Without the call to `resource.setrlimit` the program should finish normally (on typical hardware).

---

You can also limit the total CPU time available with:

```
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CPU, (n, n))
```

where `n` is given in seconds. For example,

```
In [1]: import math

In [2]: x = math.factorial(40000)

In [3]: import resource

In [4]: resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CPU, (2, 2))

In [5]: x = math.factorial(40000)

Process Python killed
```

The process was killed since it could not compute `40000!` in 2 seconds.

---

Note that both these commands affect the entire PyDev session, not just one command.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work on my machine as I am on Windows. Is there a Windows solution?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the equivalent solution for Windows.